# c++ memory leak in constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I need to create 2 classes, and second class must have pointer to first object as its member. My program works, but there are memory leaks, and I can't fix them. I know, that the problem is in constructor or destructor, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "classes.h"

int main() {
COne firstObj;
CTwo secondObj;

firstObj.setN(10);
firstObj.setS("candies");
firstObj.print();

secondObj.setS("cookies");
secondObj.setP(&firstObj);
cout<<endl;
secondObj.print();

return 0;
}
```

classes.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class COne {
private:
    int n;
    string sOne;

public:
    COne(int n2create = 0, const string& sOne2create = "");

    COne(const COne& obj);

    ~COne();

    COne& operator=(const COne& obj);

    void setN(int n2set);

    void setS(const string &sOne2set);

    int getN() const;

    string getS() const;

    void print() const;
};

class CTwo {
private:
    string sTwo;
    COne* p;

public:
    CTwo(string sTwo2create = "", COne& p2create = *(new COne()));

    CTwo(const CTwo& obj);

    ~CTwo();

    CTwo& operator=(const CTwo& obj);

    void setS(string sTwo2set);

    void setP(COne* p2set);

    string getS() const;

    COne* getP() const;

    void print() const;
};

#endif
```

classes.cpp

```
#include "classes.h"

COne::COne(int n2create, const string& sOne2create) :n(n2create), sOne(sOne2create) {}

COne::COne(const COne& obj) :n(obj.n), sOne(obj.sOne) {}

COne::~COne() {}

COne& COne::operator=(const COne& obj){
    n = obj.n;
    sOne = obj.sOne;
    return *this;
}

void COne::setN(int n2set) {n = n2set;}

void COne::setS(const string& sOne2set) {sOne = sOne2set;}

int COne::getN() const {return n;}

string COne::getS() const {return sOne;}

void COne::print() const {
    cout<<"COne object:"<<endl;
    cout<<"n = "<<n<<endl;
    cout<<"sOne = \""<<sOne<<"\""<<endl;
}

CTwo::CTwo(string sTwo2create, COne& p2create) :sTwo(sTwo2create), p(new COne(p2create)) {}

CTwo::CTwo(const CTwo& obj) :sTwo(obj.sTwo), p(new COne (*obj.p)){}

CTwo::~CTwo() {delete p;}

CTwo& CTwo::operator=(const CTwo& obj){
    sTwo = obj.sTwo;
    p = obj.p;
    return *this;
}

void CTwo::setS(string sTwo2set) {sTwo = sTwo2set;}

void CTwo::setP(COne* p2set) {p = p2set;}

string CTwo::getS() const {return sTwo;}

COne* CTwo::getP() const {return p;}

void CTwo::print() const {
    cout<<"CTwo object:"<<endl;
    cout<<"sTwo = \""<<sTwo<<"\""<<endl;
    cout<<"p: n = "<<p->getN()<<", sOne = \""<<p->getS()<<"\""<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to fix memory leaks is to eliminate all `new`s from your code and use only containers and smart pointers.

Comment: but what's the issue you're having? what's the error you're getting?

Comment: @AchinthaGunasekara The issue is a memory leak, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, in:

```
COne& p2create = *(new COne())
```

You have a memory leak if the argument is default constructed. This is because `p2create` is a reference to a dynamically allocated object and you then copy it into another dynamically allocated object only to store the latter and never free the former.

Specifically in:

```
CTwo::CTwo(string sTwo2create, COne& p2create) :sTwo(sTwo2create), p(new COne(p2create)) {}
```

Your code contains other errors of course. To solve them all, just rewrite your classes to:

```
struct COne {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "COne object:\n"
                  << "n = " << n << '\n'
                  << "s = \"" << s << "\"\n";
    }
};

struct CTwo {
    std::string sTwo;
    COne p;
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "CTwo object:\n"
                  << "sTwo = \"" << sTwo << "\"\n"
                  << "p: n = "<< p.n << ", s = \"" << p.s <<"\"\n";
    }
};
```

which are functionally equivalent, and then use them as:

```
int main() {
    COne firstObj {10, "candies"};
    firstObj.print();

    std::cout << '\n';

    CTwo secondObj {"cookies", firstObj};
    secondObj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbdd15b31bb231c1)

Answer (score 0):

```
void CTwo::setP(COne* p2set) {p = p2set;}
```

Saves the new pointer, overwriting the previous value of p without deleting any previously allocated memory assigned to p.